# Expected type Union[str, bytes, int] but got Sequence[Union[int, float, str]]

Tags: python, linter

PyCharm is showing this warning and I cannot figure out why.

```
def record(self, *data: Sequence[Union[int, float, str]]) -> None:

    for field, value in zip(self.fields, data):
        if field.type in {1, 3}:
            try:
                value = int(value)  # warning is here
            except ValueError:
                pass

    # other logic...
```

Its saying that `value` from the unpacked `zip` is the same type as the argument `data`, but its not nor should it be. If it was an element of a `Sequence` that would mean it would be a `Union[int, float, str]` type.

Does PyCharm not realize that `zip` was unpacked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#arbitrary-argument-lists-and-default-argument-values), the type hint applies to each *element* of `*data`, not the sequence itself. You don't need `Sequence`; that is already implied by the `*`.

```
def record(self, *data: Union[int, float, str]) -> None:
```